# update properties file at runtime

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee

I have one Project (say A) which uses Spring. Project A internally depends on other project (Say B) for few Task. So B Project URL is configurable in server.properties file of A Project.

So now each time URL for B project get changed then I have to shutdown A Project, change the URL in server.properties file and then again start the server.

So I have requirement as to ask user to enter the new URL using GUI and change the URL at runtime.

I know it is possible to change the value of the property at runtime but it will be set only for that session and not an actual modification to properties file, and once the server is restarted again it will refer to old URL because actual changes are present in Session and not to actual Properties file.

my actual need is that changes should be reflected in properties file(for future restart of server it should work) as well as in beans configuration File(for current session - I am aware of how to do.)

Now my requirement is, whenever any changes comes in configuration then it should also physically change the properties file...is there any neat way to do this instead of reading File and search for that key and then replace substring.

Is there any third party api to do this nicely.

Answer (score 0):

You can look at [commons configuration](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/). See file based save and reload [here](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/userguide/howto_filebased.html#File-based_Configurations).

Comment: Hey Adi, I will have a look on this and also if you got my question correctly then please suggest some good solution on how one should handle such situation except what I told to change he properties file.

Answer (score 0):

You can update properties file at runtime by using [Commons Configuration API](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-configuration/) then get value by key. Here is good working [example update and read properties](http://javabycode.com/java-core/java-io/how-to-update-properties-file-in-java.html)

Hope this help!